# Why is Null printing?

Tags: function-construction, core-language

I am making a function that will evaluate several other functions, using the same inputs, in my program and give me the results. I am using `Print` to do this (see Picture.) The problem is that one of them is printing `Null` along with the answer. Is there a way to get this `Null` to not print out? Maybe another way to write this function of functions?

```
Poly = {w1, w2, w3, w4, d} \[Function] Module[{},

Print[FFFF[w1, w2, w3, w4, d]];
Print[FFC2[w1, w2, w3, w4, d]]];
```

And it prints out:
[image: Here is what it prints out]

Here is the function that is giving the null...

```
FFC2 = {w1, w2, w3, w4, d} \[Function] 
Module[{weights, allsol, dup, sol, rsol},
weights = {w1, w2, w3, w4};
allsol = DeleteCases[DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[Table[
     If[
      l != i != j != 
        k &&
              {d/weights[[l]], 
         d/weights[[i]]} \[Element] 
        Integers &&

       Chain2[weights[[j]], weights[[k]], d] != {},

      Flatten[{d/weights[[l]], d/weights[[i]],    
        Take[Chain2[weights[[j]], weights[[k]], d], 2], 
        weights[[l]],
        weights[[i]], 
        Drop[Chain2[weights[[j]], weights[[k]], d], 2]}, 1],
                         {}] , {l, 4}, {i, 4}, {j, 4}, {k, 4}], 
    3]], {}]; 
dup = DeleteCases[
  Flatten[Table[
    If[i < j && 
      Sort[Take[Drop[allsol[[i]], 4], 2]] == 
       Sort[Take[Drop[allsol[[j]], 4], 2]], allsol[[i]], {}], {i, 
     Length[allsol]}, {j, Length[allsol]}], 1], {}];
sol = Complement[allsol, dup];
If[sol == {{}} \[Or] sol == {}, "No Possible FFC2", 
 For[k = 1, k < Length[sol] + 1, k++,

  Print[StringTemplate[
   "FFC2: w^``+x^``+y^``z+z^`` with weights: {``,``,``,``}"][
  Sequence @@ Take[sol, {k}][[1]]]]]]];
```

And it prints out:
[image: Here is what this prints out]
The reason `Null` is printing is because the answer that is given by the function in the second picture is a result of `Print`, but I don't know how to have the answer print without it.

Comment: It would be far more useful to have actual cut-and-pastable code, rather than an image.

Comment: The `Null` is the return value of the function `FFC2`. It is probably the value of the expression with head `For`... Note that `Print` is _not_ the right way to return the result of a function.

Comment: What is the right way to return the result of a function?

Comment: We'll be able to show you how if you can edit your question to include code the rest of us can copy.

Comment: I have updated the post

Answer (score 3):

Here are two similar functions:

```
f1[x_] := Module[{t = x^2},
    Print[t]
]

f2[x_] := Module[{t = x^2},
    t
]
```

The first function prints something, and returns the output of a [`Print`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Print) statement, which is [`Null`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Null). The second function returns `t`. The second function is the usual way of defining a function using [`Module`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module) in Mathematica. The very last statement is the return value *(note: it is possible to wrap the last statement in [`Return`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Return), but this is discouraged because it is not always clear what data structure a [`Return`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Return) statement is returning from)*. Let's compare `f1` and `f2`:

```
In[36]:= f1[2] // InputForm

During evaluation of In[36]:= 4

Out[36]//InputForm=
Null
```

Notice how 4 is printed in a [`Print`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Print) cell, and the output is simply [`Null`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Null) (the [`InputForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputForm) is needed because in [`StandardForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StandardForm), [`Null`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Null) outputs are suppressed). Now, compare this with:

```
In[37]:= f2[2]

Out[37]= 4
```

The above explains what you're seeing. The return value of `FFC2` is [`Null`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Null), as the last statement of `FFC2` is a [`Print`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Print) statement. Printing the output of `FFC2` thus prints [`Null`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Null). It is similar to:

```
In[41]:= Module[{},
    Print[f1[2]]
  ] // InputForm

During evaluation of In[41]:= 4

During evaluation of In[41]:= Null

Out[41]//InputForm=
Null
```

I would discourage the usage of [`Print`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Print), unless you are using it for diagnostic purposes.